# Images uploads with old url and wont show up

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have migrated from host to my new host 
everything is working good but when i upload a image to my media it goes with old URL and wont even show up
the thing is the image actually uploads , i know that from filezilla cause it goes into the uploads folder
what is the problem? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Your domain may not have fully propagated yet. Did you just change hosts within the last few hours or so?

Comment: GIve us an example of what the old URL is and what the new URL is. I have trouble grasping this question and show us some sample code of the said images.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i ve changed the hosts about a mouth ago
old url is : s.com , new is : a.com
i ve changed host like i always do by define them in config file 
but now when i go to my dashboard and media and upload a pic , the pic is broken and the url is s.com , but in filezila the broken pic exists is uploads folder

Comment: There's probably something in your config file(s) that contains the old URL. That, and/or if you uploaded via a form and stored it in a DB containing the old URL, then that could be it.

Comment: uploaded via form ? i didnt understand that part

Answer (score 0):

Edit functions.php

If you have access to the site via FTP, then this method will help you quickly get a site back up and running, if you changed those values incorrectly.

1. FTP to the site, and get a copy of the active theme's functions.php file. You're going to edit it in a simple text editor (like notepad) and upload it back to the site.
2. Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial "

update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');

Use your own URL instead of example.com, obviously.

3. Upload the file back to your site, in the same location. FileZilla offers a handy "edit file" function to do all of the above rapidly; if you can use that, do so.
4. Load the login or admin page a couple of times. The site should come back up.
5. Repeat the above steps, but remove those lines. IMPORTANT: Do NOT leave those lines in there. Remove them immediately after the site is up and running again.